# Populate listview from database in fragment

Tags: android

I want to populate the listview from database in SocialFragment.java. I have done as below and shows error- incompatible types:SocialFragment cannot be converted to Context. Please help me to populate listview from databse in a Fragment.

SocialFragment.java

```
package layout;
        import android.app.ListActivity;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import com.example.kiran.herau.Help;
        import com.example.kiran.herau.NewDatabaseAdapter;
        import com.example.kiran.herau.R;
        import com.example.kiran.herau.VivzDatabaseAdapter;


public class SocialFragment extends Fragment {

    protected BaseAdapter mAdapter;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    NewDatabaseAdapter vivzHelper;
    TextView text;

    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.social_layout,null);
        displayListView(view);
return view;
    }

    private void displayListView(View view) {

        vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(this);
        Cursor cursor = vivzHelper.fetchAllData();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[] {

                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.UID,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.NAME,
                NewDatabaseAdapter.NewDatabaseHelper.ADDRESS,

        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[] {
                R.id.id,
                R.id.name,
                R.id.address,
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information

        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.routinerow,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(getActivity()) ?

Comment: Post error logs. Where are you getting an error?

Comment: dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.routinerow,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);
It is underlined with red in android studio.

Comment: replace `this` with `getActivity()`.

Comment: it isnot working by replacing this with getActivity();

Comment: have you tried "SocialFragment.this" instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace

```
vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(this);
```

with:

```
vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
```

And you need to replace:

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.routinerow,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);
```

with:

```
dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(), R.layout.routinerow,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);
```

This should help you out, hopefully :)

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer Exception at these lines. listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);          displayListView(view);

Comment: @Nitez Log your cursor, columns and to variables to make sure they are not null.

Comment: Thank you. I have successfully made it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass activity's context to Database helper class to instantiate.

Here you are passing Fragment's its not a context pass its activity's context by using getActivity()

Try,

```
vivzHelper = new NewDatabaseAdapter(getActivity())
```

Comment: please elaborate.

Comment: @Nitez post this NewDatabaseAdapter class?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
Context context ;
onCreateView(){
   context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
   ....
   dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                context, R.layout.routinerow,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);
}
```